# Pulling cost field from a sub-query

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I wrote the following query to pull a unit cost from another table `COSreport` into my profitability query `ProfitabilityReport` and am having a problem with my sub-query.

```
select 
i.tranid
, it.item_id
, it.displayname
, tl.Item_Count * -1 Unit_Qty
, case when tl.Item_Count=0 then 0 
         else ((tl.GROSS_AMOUNT * -1)/ Item_Count) * -1 
end as PricePerUnit,

**(select sum(c.tranamt) from ns.COSreport c
  inner join ns.ProfitabilityReport d
  on c.InvoiceID = d.tranid 
and c.item_id = d.item_id) as 'True Cost'**

, '0' 'Cost Per M'

from ns.tinvoice i
join ns.transaction_lines tl on i.transaction_id = tl.transaction_id
join ns.Customers cust on c.customer_id = i.ENTITY_ID
join ns.items it on it.item_id = tl.item_id
left join ns.ITEM_CLASSIFICATION it_class on it_class.list_id = 
it.ITEM_CLASSIFICATION_ID
where list_item_name IS NOT NULL
and i.tranid = '1262INV'
```

I'm joining on both the `invoice id` and `item id` so that the proper cost is pulled across for the given invoice and item from `COSReport`.

However, the true cost is not coming up with the unit cost but instead is summing up the cost field for the entire table.

See below for example using invoice # 1262INV specified in the query above. The cost should be 1.04, .26, and 4 respectively vs 138m.

[image]

Any help getting this cleared up would be appreciated

Comment: It looks like you're missing your `FROM` clause from the main query. You can probably take the subquery out of the `SELECT` list and join it to your main table as a correlated subquery. But we'd need to see the `FROM` clause in order to properly build the correlated join.

Comment: Reusing an alias it a really bad idea too. You have `ns.COSreport c` and `ns.Customers c`. I suggest using unique aliases that represent your objects.

Comment: Sorry, that line was mistakenly removed - it's now been added

Comment: Thank you - aliases have been updated in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually prefer using CTEs for readability. You can take your subquery, put it into a CTE, and then join it in your main query, but you'll want to add the `tranid` and `item_id` fields to the CTE so you can use them in your join.

EDIT: since you're using Azure SQL Server, you don't need the semicolon before the `WITH`.

```
WITH TrueCosts AS
(
    SELECT
        d.tranid 
        ,d.item_id
        ,TrueCost = SUM(c.tranamt) 
    FROM ns.COSreport c
    INNER JOIN ns.ProfitabilityReport d
        ON c.InvoiceID = d.tranid 
            AND c.item_id = d.item_id
    GROUP BY d.tranid 
        ,d.item_id
)
SELECT 
    i.tranid
    , it.item_id
    , it.displayname
    , tl.Item_Count * -1 Unit_Qty
    , case when tl.Item_Count=0 then 0 
             else ((tl.GROSS_AMOUNT * -1)/ Item_Count) * -1 
        END as PricePerUnit
    , tc.TrueCost AS 'True Cost'
    , '0' AS 'Cost Per M'
FROM ns.tinvoice i
JOIN ns.transaction_lines tl on i.transaction_id = tl.transaction_id
JOIN ns.Customers c on c.customer_id = i.ENTITY_ID
JOIN ns.items it on it.item_id = tl.item_id
LEFT JOIN ns.ITEM_CLASSIFICATION it_class on it_class.list_id = it.ITEM_CLASSIFICATION_ID
LEFT JOIN TrueCosts tc ON tc.tranid = i.tranid AND tc.item_id = tl.item_id
WHERE list_item_name IS NOT NULL
    AND i.tranid = '1262INV'
```

Comment: Thanks! Got the following error - The multi-part identifier "tc.TrueCost" could not be bound. You're already summing so I shouldn't need to sum again, should I?

Comment: You're correct, the summing is happening in the CTE, so you won't need to SUM in the main query. As for the error you're getting, did you add the `LEFT JOIN TrueCosts...` line into your main query?

Comment: looks like that was missing, am now getting Incorrect syntax near ';'. (102) so looking at what could be causing that

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? The only semicolon is at the very beginning of the query, and CTEs require a semicolon before the `WITH`. Maybe you have an error in your script before this query?

Comment: Azure SQL Server

Comment: Just remove the semicolon, then

Comment: Sure enough! It's always the small things :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems.

In your subquery you use the alias `c` for `COSReport`.   You also use the alias `c` for `customers` in your outer query.

The bigger problem is that your subquery isn't correlated to your outer query at all.  That's why it's summing up the entire table.

To correlate your subquery, you need to join (in the subquery) to one of the tables in the outer query.   Not sure of your tables or data, but at a guess, I'd say you want to use `ns.tinvoice i` in a WHERE clause in your subquery.